# When is it appropriate to create HTML code in the controller (or back end)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, separation-of-concerns

I am doing some complex logic involving loads of recursion to create a (complex) piece of HTML.

I started off doing this in the View using functions in Razor because I felt as HTML it belonged there.

But as it started getting more complex I thought I would rather do it in back-end code. Which it currently is.

It still feels a bit smellish though, and I am wondering if I should move it to the View again (which obviously clutters the view)

Which technically is more correct? When is it appropriate to use back-end code to generate HTML?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Will it be complex if you use partial view?

Comment: You could still maintain a clear separation between your View and Controller logic if you put the complex Html generation code into a helper class which you then use from your view.  The controller therefore still only provides the data to the view and the view generates the UI from the data.

Comment: i have seperated the business logic out of the controller into a "manager", so the controller is really only passing it along. i still feel it is the same end though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it in controller. You can extend the [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class and do the stuff there. For example if you are using a paging helper.

Create a static class HtmlHelpers

```
namespace YourMvcApplication.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,int totalPages)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            // do the complex logic to create dynamic html and append to 
            // String Builder
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Add reference to this class in all views in web.config.

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="YourMvcApplication.WebUI.HtmlHelpers"/>
</namespaces>
```

Use and resuse this Html Helper methods wherever required.

```
<div>
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.TotalPages)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

create more granular partial views and partial models to maintain MVC pattern.

when your correctly select a model for your view, even partial, generating HTML in view is not a problem. you may end up with 20 views and 5 more models, but controller will be just selecting views and populating models which is good.